# FILE-pointer "outdated?"

Tags: c

Hi I have been starting to learn a little bit about FILE-pointer and how to open a file,etc..
I'm reading the book C Primer Plus Fifth Edition by Stephen Prata ( SamsPublishing ) 
and I can't even get the solutions they have to work in my project.

This is how it looks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int byte;
FILE * source;
int filect;


if (argc == 1)
{
    printf("Usage: %s filename[s]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (filect = 1; filect < argc; filect++)
{
    if ((source = fopen(argv[filect], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file %s for input\n", argv[filect]);    
        continue;
    }
    while ((byte = getc(source)) != EOF)
    {
        putchar(byte);
    }
    if (fclose(source) != 0)
        printf("Could not close file %s\n", argv[1]);
}    
    return 0;
}`
```

The output is:Usage:(Where my c project is located) filename[s]
push down any key to continue... Why is this happening?

Comment: [Looks like reasonable output to me.](http://ideone.com/2e9M6p) Are you passing arguments to the executable?

Comment: How are you running your program?  It looks like it expects you to pass it a filename on the command line i.e. `./myprog [filename]` on linux or `myprog.exe [filename]` on Windows.

Comment: Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with a FILE-pointer, your title is very misleading.

Comment: You should understand the basics of running a C program, passing arguments to it, before doing things as opening files. The title of the question has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`argv[0]` **can** refer to the directory the executable is in when you run the program. The standard states the following:

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name; argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment.

The arguments passed to an application via command line can be accessed starting from `argv[1]` up to `argv[argc - 1]`.

Comment: AFIK `argv[0]` points to a string containing the name of the executable

Comment: @A4L: `argv[0]` points to a string that "represents the *program name*". The manner in which it does so is unspecified, and can vary from one system to another; it's not even required to be meaningful.

Comment: @A4L: It gets a bit odder than that.  It seems to be the name *by which the program was invoked* in Linux, for example; if you run the program via a symlink with a different name, `argv[0]` will be the name of the link, not of the executable.  Some programs (like Vim) use this to run in different operating modes depending on what name was used to start them.

Comment: I seem to remember programs even being able to change it...to change what shows in `ps`, for example.  But i might be misremembering; it's been a while.

Comment: @cHao and  KeithThompson, thanks for your pointings, didn't know that it is not requied that `argv[0]` musst be the name of the file used to start the program (actually this is what I meant by executable, I admit that it was not precise).

Comment: @Magtheridon96 from what you have quoted program argument always start at argv[1]? ... upvote since your answer should help the questioner understand what he is doing wrong.

Comment: The name of the program actually counts as an argument itself, but the developer of a command line tool would only care about the ones given after the program name, which happen to start at argv[1] ;P